# Parse - check to see if column has null value associated with it

Tags: android, sqlite, parse-platform

I'm trying to fill my applications sqlite table using values obtained from querying from parse. I have three columns that can possibly have null values, how do you perform a null check for these columns? I have tried .get() != null or .getString() != null but these have not worked. 
On another note, what is the difference between undefined and null on parse?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to check is that an underlying cursor column is null, then try:

```
.isNull(columnIndex)
```